# Howto generate browser info using the microsoft c++ compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-construction, gnu

I have been using the Metrowerks Codewarrior IDE for many years. It's C/C++ compiler generates what Metrowerks calls 'browser info'. This browser info makes it possible to double click a typename/functioname and automatically the correct file is openend displaying the definition.

Now the mentioned IDE has the possibility to use external toolchains (compiler,linker etc.) by means of plugins. I have succesfully created compiler and linker plugins for both the Microsoft as the GNU toolchains. The only thing I don't know is how the generate the mentioned 'browser info'. Which command line do I have to execute to get the information I need?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler flag /FR generates browser info files: [/FR, /Fr (Create .Sbr File)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fr-fr-create-dot-sbr-file), and then you can use bscmake to compile these into a .bsc file.

However I've no idea how you'd consume these .sbr files or .bsc file in your plugin. I guess you'll need to find a DLL or COM interface from Visual Studio to give you something to work with. There are other options e.g. map files if they're easier to consume and have enough information for you.

Comment: The codewarrior IDE plugin API has callback functions and datatypes for this purpose. Things you have to specify include the source file, the starting and ending offset in the file where a certain symbol is defined.

Comment: By the way, thank you for you're answer. I appreciate it.